Python webbrowser.open not using default browser
In my Python program
webbrowser.open('etc..')

opens Microsoft Edge. Now the strange thing is, I have another Python program in a slightly different folder than opens Chrome (my default). Any ideas as to what's going on?
(I know similar has been asked but this seems very strange)
I even pointed Edge to open Chrome and it's still not having it!
Edit
Just made a new Python file in the same place as the problem one with
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open('google.com')

And it opened Chrome. What on earth is happening? Could it be the way the link from the program is handled? It looks like this:
link = "https://www.example.com"+threadId
webbrowser.open(link)


This question is similar to: python's webbrowser launches IE, instead of default browser, on Windows relative path. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

relative path != proper webpage, thanks anyway


Interesting...
Turns out not having https at the start of the link made it open Edge instead
Trial and error prevail!

Would be interesting to know why this happens though.

the duplicate talks exactly about this... looks like you haven't read it
